# How to do a Bulk Insert -- Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I cannot find any examples on how to do a Bulk/batch insert using Linq to Entities. Do you guys know how to do a Bulk Insert?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sometimes you simply have to mix models. Perhaps use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for this part of your repository (since this plugs directly into the bulk-copy API), and Entity Framework for some of the rest. And if necessary, a bit of direct ADO.NET. Ultimately the goal is to get the job done.

Answer (score 12):

For a perfect example of how to do bulk inserts with LINQ to Entities, see http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader. It is a wrapper that allows easy use of SqlBulkCopy.

@Marc Gravell is correct, sometimes you have to mix models to get the job done.

Comment: found it here ... https://github.com/matthewschrager/Repository/blob/master/Repository.EntityFramework/EntityDataReader.cs

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a class that will bulk insert EF entities (or any kind of object as long as the property names match the column names).

The class supports customizing the batch size, pre & post insert events, queued inserts, and "firehose mode" (give it a billion objects, it will respect the batch size).

- The code: [`BulkInserter<T>`](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs)
- [How to use it](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/wiki/Bulk-Inserter)

Answer (score 2):

For inserting a huge amount of data in a database, I used to collect all the inserting information into a list and convert this list into a `DataTable`. I then insert that list to a database via `SqlBulkCopy`.

Where I send my generated list 
`LiMyList`
 which contain information of all bulk data which I want to insert to database
 and pass it to my bulk insertion operation

```
InsertData(LiMyList, "MyTable");
```

Where `InsertData` is

```
 public static void InsertData<T>(List<T> list,string TabelName)
        {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
                clsBulkOperation blk = new clsBulkOperation();
                dt = ConvertToDataTable(list);
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolSoulDataEntitiesForReport"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 660;
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = TabelName;
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                }
        }    

public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }
```