# insert a list of object to table

Tags: entity-framework-4

context.AddObject("User",myuserobjetc)
This add a user to the User table.
how can i insert a list of users to user table(with out looping)?

entity-framework-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can not do bulk insert with EF4. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609153/how-to-do-a-bulk-insert-linq-to-entities) is another topic about that.