# Linq and adding a large amount of data

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-entities, out-of-memory, large-data

I need insert to large amount of data to `sqlite` db.
I uses `Linq to Entities`.

I have problem to adding large amount of data **1M+**.
Not enough memory or a very long time.

This code - fast, but requires a lot of memory:

```
// query - IQueryable of DbfRecord
// db - ObjectContext
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in query) {
    db.AddToKladrs(new Kladr() {
        Id = item.GetField(0),
        ParentId = item.GetField(1),
        RegionId = item.GetField(3),
        Name = item.GetField(2),
        Index = item.GetField(4)
    });
    if(++i % 4000 == 0)
        db.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
}
```

This code - not resource-intensive, but **very slow**:

```
// query - IQueryable of DbfRecord
// db - ObjectContext
foreach (var item in query) {
    db.ExecuteStoreCommand("insert into [Kladr] values({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4})",
        item.GetField(0),
        item.GetField(1),
        item.GetField(3),
        item.GetField(2),
        item.GetField(4)
    );
}
```

*I missed the try-catch construction and ghost types.*

Help me find the best solution!

Comment: Saving every row or every 4000 rows is a pretty extreme split. Have you tried saving every, say, 100 or 200?

Comment: Of course, then decreases productivity. But 4000 is chosen at random =) but it works fast!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SqlBulkCopy` for copying large amounts of data. Havn't tried it with SQL lite but it should work.

[Link 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlBulkCopy.aspx) 
[Link 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx)

Update :

Here is a good answer by Marc Gravell. [how-to-do-a-bulk-insert-linq-to-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609153/how-to-do-a-bulk-insert-linq-to-entities)

Comment: this don't work with `DbConnection`. I cann't conver `SQLiteConnection` (`DbConnection`) to `SqlConnection` =( i uses `System.Data.SQLite`

Comment: I just found that Bulk insert is not supported by sqlite, however you can use a transaction which will do the same thing.