# Bulk Insert in mysql Table using Linq to entity

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-entities

I have millions of record that I want to insert in mysql table and I am using linq to entity for this. I want that it will use minimum database resource for inserting records.

Any bulk insertion idea that will help me. Please suggest me that how can I use minimum resources.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609153/how-to-do-a-bulk-insert-linq-to-entities

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Comment: @rahularyansharma  Both Example is not running. And I need help for Linq to entity. Because i am using linq to entity.